# Angular 2 Generate Div Dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-template

It is possible to generate a div with content and join a compoment ? For example in my code I have a button and clicking on it would generate a new div with content and add to the content that was before this is possible?

Example of div

```
 <div [hidden]="inicial2"  #destroy>
    <button (click) = "esconde(); destroy.remove()">back</button>
      <br>
     Testa <input type="text" name=""> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand you correct..

but *ngIf will `remove` it and show the other div.

```
<div *ngIf="!inicial2" #destroy>
   <button (click) = "esconde(); inicial2 = !inicial2;">back</button>
   <br>
   Testa <input type="text" name=""> 
</div>
<div *ngIf="inicial2">
  ..
</div>
```

Comment: I want to generate a div i have a function which I built the div when i click a button but my problem and adds it to the component

Comment: Show that function please, why its built dynamically? maybe we can reach the same goal with angular's templates too.

Comment: For example 
`generatediv($randomid)
 {
  var div = '<div [hidden]="inicial3"  #destroy2> <button (click) = "esconde(); destroy2.remove > {{randomid}}</div>';
  return div;
 }`

Comment: why is it generated? and when? please update your answer with full use-case. its not possible add dynamic content WITH angular-events inside.